# Free radical vs radical cation

Tags: ions, terminology, radicals

What is the difference between a free radical and a radical cation?  Are they different thing or do they mean same?

Comment: The difference is one electron ;-)

Comment: @KlausWarzecha Not always: radical dications...?

Comment: Related: The answer to http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/9579 gives one example for the generation of a radical cation and how it is converted to a radical.

Answer (score 6):

A *radical cation* is simply a *free radical* with a positive charge. Similarly a *radical anion* is a free radical with a negative charge.

In other words, *radical cations* and *radical anions* are subsets of the *free radicals*.

That said, the term *free radical* itself is not entirely clear cut, as illustrated in [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/440/what-makes-a-radical-free).